# Copy files and set owner/group to the owner/group of the destination directory

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, cp

I have a script used in different environments. This scripts uses `sudo cp` to copy files (sudo otherwise it has no access). But `sudo cp` creates the files with the wrong owner. It cannot keep the owner of the source files because these to are the wrong ones. Also the owner of the destination directories are different in the locations where this script is used.

Is there a way to `sudo cp` and set the owner/group to the destination directory owner/group?

Comment: I would invoke `chown` to set the desired owner to the copied files.

Comment: That ^^  or don't use cp? Use for instance rsync.

Comment: It is a script, I don't know the owner/group beforehand

Comment: Just a note when using sudo, it may be better to run sudo on the script file instead of cp. Sudo uses a simple string match on the supplied command, so it's not analyzing the script. It is a balance, what "command" should have sudo rights, but giving sudo rights to cp may cause a lot of harm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've settled with this:

After copying the directory:

```
sudo cp ${SOURCE_DIR} ${DEST_DIR}
```

Changing the owner/group with this:

```
sudo chown "$(stat -c '%U:%G' ${DEST_DIR})" -R ${DEST_DIR}/copied_dir
```

**update 2020-11-16**:

Use the [--reference](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) option of `chown` like this:

```
 sudo chown --reference ${DEST_DIR} -R ${DEST_DIR}/copied_dir
```

Answer (score 9):

`install` will give you options to set user/group and mode when copying and creating directories.

```
sudo install -o user -g group -D -t target/ file1 file2
```

Comment: The issue is that the owner / group are different in the places were the script is run. So I do not know the user / group beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [--preserve](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cp#:%7E:text=%2D%2Dpreserve%5B%3DATTR_LIST%5D) option of `cp` like this:

```bash
sudo cp --preserve /path/to/file /path/to/file2
```

Comment: The --preserve option of cp retains the original ownership of the source file.  By default, cp does what the question asks.